# Getting my nav menu to work with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Basically I have two controllers using CodeIgniter for a simple blog for a project at school. 
One is Home which is the login page. The other is Member for when they are signed in. in this member controller I am creating functions for add_post(), view_users_posts(), etc.
Member.php

```
class Member extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in !== true) {
        redirect('home');
    }
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'index.php/member/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('posts')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['posts'] = $this->posts_model->get_all_posts($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->load->view('member_view', $data);
}

public function add_post() {
    $this->load->view('add_post_view');
}
```

My member view has a nav menu with links to these functions like so:
member_view.php

```
      <li><a href="member">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="member/add_post">Add Post</a></li>
      <li><a href="member/view_users_posts">My Posts</a></li>
      <li><a href="member/reset_pass">Reset Password</a></li>
      <li><a href="member/logout">Logout</a></li>
```

I haven't finished them as I am having trouble knowing what to code. Basically if the user clicks Add Post should it refer to the function add_post in the controller which will load a view called add_post? Or should it direct to a new controller called Add_post that will load the view?

My reason is if I click add post it takes me to member/add_post but when I click back home I get member/member then add post again I get member/member/add_post.

I hope this makes sense, I am at a total loss. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `base url`.

Suppsoe your base url is (in the config), www.example.com/

then your code will be

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('member/add_post');?>">Add Post</a></li>
```

Do the same for other items.

**Note:** Remember slash in the config file. otherwise include it in `base_url('/member/add_post')`

[Reference](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had used the base url wrong previously. I had to add in the index.php cause I haven't removed that yet but it works now! Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. If it solved your problem, mark this answer as accepted as some other user, who may be facing same problem as you, will find it useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.
For the menu items you have, you would have to complete these controller functions:

```
class Member extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in !== true) {
            redirect('home');
    }

    function add_post()
    {
        // for example:
        $this->load->view('header');  // standard header and menu view
        $this->load->view('add_post');  // input form view
        $this->load->view('footer');   // standard footer, adverts, etc.
    }

    function view_users_posts()
    {
        $data ['posts'] = $this->model->get_all_posts( ...(etc)... );
        $this->load->view('header');  // standard header and menu view
        $this->load->view('view_users_posts', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');   // standard footer, adverts, etc.
    }

    function reset_pass()
    {
        ...
    }

    function logout()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The first new function references `views/header.php`, `views/add_post.php`, and `views/footer.php`.  The other "member" functions should probably also load header and footer (for a consistent site look) but load a different main body of functionality, probably called something very similar to the functions.

I have assumed `view_users_posts()` accesses some new model function to retrieve the posts, passes it along to the view to format appropriately.  Note that `view/view_users_posts.php` should access the variable `$posts` based on the way I wrote it above.

Comment: @itachi:  My sites don't use base URL in the navbar, and they work fine.  I do start them with a leading `/` though.

Comment: Yes it was the nav menu, but I do need this info for my functions as I complete them. Thanks!

Comment: @wallyk that's strange. you should have same problem as the poster mentioned _My reason is if I click add post it takes me to member/add_post but when I click back home I get member/member then add post again I get member/member/add_post._ I played around a bit and saw the same problem when not adding base_url or site_url.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago i had the same problem. My Solution was that is set the base url to the path to the index.php. For example

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/"
```

so you can use it like this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>Controller/Action/Param1/Param2">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: I would have but my stylesheets are all linked already and would have to go back and fix all of them. Will do this next time though, thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can  implement a function that echo's your Base url in a helper class and load the helper on startup via the config Array. Look CI's documentation at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html. hope this could help

Comment: I have a tip for you. Have a Look at Symfony 2. Please don't understand me wrong, but i think CodeIgniter is a bit stuck. Php 5.3 has added so many cool Features like Namespaces and so on that you have to be a dumbass if you don't use them. CodeIgniter is a cool Framework for small Webapps, but since i have seen the Magic of Symfony 2, there is no other Framework for me.