# How to implement navigation menu in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i have implemented a navigation menu in codeigniter php.But when i click on menu it is getting as access forbidden.Here is the code which i have done.Thank You

Controller:

```
public function aboutus()
{       
    $data['mainpage'] = 'aboutus';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

View:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/aboutus">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/contact">Contact Us</a></li>   
   </ul>
```

Comment: Is "aboutus" inside of "welcome" controller?

Comment: yes i have tried by creating about us as a different controller also it is getting the same issue as access forbidden.

Comment: Can anyone help me this

Comment: did you check `base_url()`? is it correct?

Comment: ya i have checked base_url() it is working for home page but not for any other links

Comment: There's not enough for us to properly diagnose.

Comment: Anyway. Refer this question. I don't want to copy the code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632016/getting-my-nav-menu-to-work-with-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At First set your base_url in config file (if not set).**

> Edit config file: application->config->config.php

Find **$config['base_url']** and set your applicaiton root url:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_application_name/'; //example localhost's
```

**View:**

> (If controller name="welcome" and action "aboutus", "contact"
>   exist in welcome controller):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/aboutus');?>">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/contact');?>">Contact Us</a></li> 
</ul>
```

**mod_rewrite problem:**

> Sometime you may face problem As CI url is like:

```
http://localhost/your_application_name/index.php/controller_name/action_name
```

Because of exist "index.php" in your url, you may become confused why your url is not working (if you type without index.php). And also it is bad to see "index.php", so you should remove it following: 
**For Apache server** 
(Like XAMPP, WAMP, php_build_in etc) then use .htaccess file in main root. (i am sharing a working .htaccess code).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**For Nginx** 
convert the .htaccess code from online like: https://winginx.com/en/htaccess
and see documentation from nginx official site.

Comment: if not work then might be problem in .htaccess file. 
Because real url is like:
http://localhost/your_application_name/index.php/controller_name/action_name
it is bad to see index.php. SO add .htaccess in application root.
.htaccess file:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sample/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>  This is my .htaccess file

Comment: Testing purpose delete your .htaccess file (take a backup). And replace your view file following:

`<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/welcome/aboutus');?>">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/welcome/contact');?>">Contact Us</a></li> 
</ul>`


just added index.php

Comment: Okay got it.

please copy my .htaccess code that i shared before. And replace your .htaccess file.
Then go back your view file (remove index.php).

Comment: Not getting what you are saying

Comment: I have edited my answer. See it. 

**i have said : use again in view:**
`<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/aboutus');?>">About Us</a></li> <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/contact');?>">Contact Us</a></li> </ul>`

**and Replace your .htaccess :**


`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

check the

> constructor function of the controller
>
> any model loaded by the
>
> controller auto loaded models
>
> constructor function for authentication checks.

and try using `<?php echo base_url('welcome/contact');?>`

Comment: about constructor function of the controller is their any check

Comment: i am not getting you what you are saying

Comment: i men the function __construct() function is their any authentication check ??? that redirecting it to forbidden page

Comment: Tried this  <?php echo base_url('welcome/contact');?> not werking same error

Comment: which screen shot i need to post how to place a screen shot